# HTML5 / CSS3 Floating Issue

Tags: html, css, css-float

It's been about 5 years since my intro to website design class and I just wanted to add a clickable image below my nav float left and when I added it, it took up the css properties of the nav left div since it was inside the div. So i put it in its own div and when i cleared both on it to bring it below the nav for some reason it seems connected to the sidebar div and it gets cleared too and is at the same height as the image for some reason and i don't know how to fix it. I have researched floating with css and can't seem to find my solution.
Thank you

image of the website issue => [website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpoNw.jpg)

Below is the HTML for the complete page but the issues lies within the div newtab & div sidebar

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Battle Ready</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="battlefield.css">
<link href="images/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon"/>
</head>
<body>
<!--The fonts I used were verdana for the body and sidebar and table 
headings, Agnes for the main titles under the banner, and BankGothic
 Md BT for the navigation.-->
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
  alert("Welcome to BattleReady.com! This page is to inform you about 
each of the playable kits on the videogame Battlefield 3 and how to 
effectively use them. If you do not have the game, you should 
definitely try it out!");
// -->
</script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
</div>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="assault.html">Assault</a></li>
      <li><a href="engineer.html">Engineer</a></li>
      <li><a href="support.html">Support</a></li>
      <li><a href="recon.html">Recon</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="newtab"
  style="clear:both;">
 <a href="images/BF3.jpg" target="_blank"><img 
src="images/BF3_thumb.png" width="101" height="128" alt="Battlefield 3 
Game Cover" style="width:101px;height:128px;border:0px;"></a>
  </div> 

  <div id="sidebar">
   <h3>Upcoming Events</h3>
    <p class="events">With purchasing Battlefield Premium&copy; you get 
 early access to future DLC. Coming out soon is DICE's new
      expansion pack "After Math" which comes out December 4th.
      For more information about Premium&copy; and other upcoming 
 expansion packs, visit
       <a href="http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/premium/" 
 target="blank">Premium</a>.</p>
   <h3>Social</h3>
    <p class="events">&bull; Dice's Battlefield 3 &nbsp;&nbsp; <a 
href="https://twitter.com/@battlefield" target="_blank">Twitter</a> 
will provide you more information
   about any upcoming changes to the game.</p>
   <p class="events">&bull; Dice's Battlefield 3 <a 
 href="https://www.facebook.com/battlefield" 
 target="_blank">Facebook</a> will showcase community videos
     and provide trailers and more information about the game.</p> 
  </div>
  <div id="center">
    <h2>What is Battle Ready?</h2>
    <p>DICE's Battlefield 3 was released October 25, 2011. Heralded as 
"The Call of Duty Killer" Battlefield 3 has lived up to the hype. 
    Whether you were
    there at the midnight release of the game or you are about to 
purchase it today the level of being ready for the battlefield is
     determined by the skill of the player. This website will develop 
 your skills and help you to be battle ready when you go boots down
      on the battlefield for the first time.</p>
      <hr>
     <h3>Battlefield 3: Why is it Special?</h3>
     <p>So you may be asking yourself, "What makes Battlefield 3 
 different from any other generic FPS on the market?" and there are a 
      plethora of reasons of why Battlefield 3 is one of the best FPS's 
on the market today. The answer to the question is simply four 
      things that Battlefield 3 has that other games don't have:</p>

     <ul>
     <li>Colossal-sized maps</li>
     <li>Realistic destruction</li>
     <li>All-terrain vehicle play</li>
     <li>The game itself centers around teamwork</li>
     </ul>
     <p> The colossal size of the maps that the player gets to play on 
 for a variety of game modes 
       helps the player to be completely emerged in the battle and 
helps give them the battlefield experience that cannot be obtained on 
      any other game. Destruction is it's finest on the game with 
DICE's new game engine Frostbite 2.0 that will make you wonder
       if you are still on a game or if it has become reality. The 
 variety of vehicles that the player gets to choose to from to operate
       are jets, tanks, jeeps, and boats.</p>
         <hr>
    <h3>Battlefield 3 Expansion Packs</h3>
   <p>Battlefield 3 will have a total of five multiplayer expansion 
packs that will further enhance your multiplayer experience. 
   The first three expansion packs (Back to Karkand, Close Quarters, 
and Armored Kill) have already been released leaving two more
  for you to wait on in anticipation. With each expansion pack the 
player gets not only maps, but also new weapons, vehicles, and 
   unique assignments that will reward the player with new weapon skins 
 as well as unlockable dog tags.</p>

   <div id="gallery">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="images/BacktoKarkand1.jpg" 
target="_blank"><img src="images/BacktoKarkand_thumb.png" width="128" 
height="71" 
            alt="Back to Karkand thumb"><span><img 
 src="images/BacktoKarkand.jpg" width="500" height="265" alt="Back to 
 Karkand">
            <br>Back to Karkand Expansion Pack</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="images/Close_Quarters1.jpg" target="_blank">
 <img src="images/close_quarters_thumb.png" width="128" height="76" 
            alt="Close Quarters thumb"><span><img 
 src="images/close_quarters.jpg" width="500" height="265" alt="Close 
 Quarters">
            <br>Close Quarters Expansion Pack</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/Armored_Kill1.jpg" target="_blank">
 <img src="images/Armored_Kill_thumb.png" width="128" height="76" 
            alt="Armored Kill thumb"><span><img 
 src="images/Armored_Kill.jpg" width="500" height="265" alt="Armored 
  Kill">
            <br>Armored Kill Expansion Pack</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="images/Aftermath1.jpg" target="_blank"><img 
 src="images/Aftermath_thumb.png" width="128" height="76" 
 alt="Aftermath thumb">
            <span><img src="images/Aftermath.jpg" width="500" 
 height="265" alt="Aftermath"><br>Aftermath Expansion Pack</span></a>
 </li>
            <li><a href="images/End_Game1.jpg" target="_blank"><img 
 src="images/End_Game_thumb.png" width="128" height="76" alt="End Game 
  thumb"><span>
                <img src="images/End_Game.jpg" width="500" height="265" 
  alt="End Game"><br>End Game Expansion Pack</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
      <div id="footer"> Copyright &copy; 2012 Battle Ready<br>
     <a href="mailto:josiahridley@gmail.com">Contact Us</a>
     </div>
   </div>
   </div>
 </body>
  </html>
```

CSS for Page:

```
/*I chose the color scheme of orange, blue, grey, and white as I 
 obtained those colors from the Battlefield 3 game cover. I chose
 orange as the headers, blue as links visited and grey as the 
 backgrounds with white and black being the text color.*/
body { margin:0;
       background-color: #000; }
 #container { background-color: #444;
         color: #fff;
         min-width: 960px;
         font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
         width:80%;
         margin-left:auto;
         margin-right:auto; 
         }
 #header {border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
    height: 120px;
    background-image: url(images/banner2.jpg);
    background-position: bottom; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding: 0 20px; }
 #nav { float: left;
   width: 150px;}
 #newtab {float:left;
      width:101px;

      }
 #sidebar{ float: right;
        clear:right;
      width: 210px;  
      background-image: url(images/background.png);
      background-position:bottom;
      background-repeat:repeat;}
 #sidebar a{ text-decoration:none;}
 #sidebar a:link { color:#F63;}
 #sidebar a:visited { color:#F03;}
 #sidebar a:focus, #sidebar a:hover { color:#FF0;}
 #sidebar a:active { color:#039;}
 #center { margin: 0 210px 0 160px;
      padding: 1px 10px 20px 10px;
      background-color: #CCC;
      color: #000; }
 #footer { font-size: .70em;
      text-align: center;
      color: #f63;
      background-color: #CCC;
      padding-top: 10px; 
      clear: both;}
     #footer a:link { color:#F63;}
     #footer a:visited { color: #039; }
      #footer a:focus, #footer a:hover { color: #FF0; }
      #footer a:active {  color: #F03;} 

 h1 { margin-top: 0; 
 font-size: 3em; 
 text-align: left;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;}
 #nav ul { font-family: "BankGothic Md BT", arial, sans-serif;
      margin-top: 20px;
      list-style-type: none; 
    }
  #nav a { text-decoration: none; 
     font-size: 1.2em;
        border:1px solid #000;
           padding:20px;
           width:70px;
        display:block;
        background-color:#CCC;
        margin-right:30px;
        margin-left:-20px;
      }
 #nav a:link { color:#F63;}
 #nav a:visited { color: #F03; }
 #nav a:focus, #nav a:hover { color: #F63;
                        background-color:blue; }
 #nav a:active {  color: #093;}

 #center p { margin: 20px; } 
 #center h2, #center h3 { font-family: "Imprint MT Shadow", Arial, 
 sans-serif;
                     color: #f63;
                     background-color: #CCC; }
 #floatright { margin: 10px;
          float: right; } 
 #sidebar h3 { padding-bottom: 2px;
          margin: 10px;
          font-size: .90em;
          color: #039;
          background-color: #CCC; 
          text-align:center;}
 .events { font-size: .80em;
         margin: 10px; }
 #gallery {position:relative;}
 #gallery ul {width:300px;
         list-style-type:none;}
 #gallery li {display:inline;
         float:left;
         padding:10px;}
 #gallery img {border-style:none;
          float:none;}
 #gallery a {text-decoration:none;
        color:#F63;
        font-style:italic;}
 #gallery span {display:none;}
 #gallery a:hover span {display:block;
                   position:absolute;
                   top:10px;
                   left:340px;
                   text-align:center;}
 #movie {text-align:center;}
 table {width:75%;
       margin:auto;
       border-collapse:collapse;
       border:outset 1px yellow;
       color:#000;}
 Caption {font-size:1.5em;
     font-weight:bold;
     color:#f63;}
th,td {border: 2px solid #039;}
thead {Background-color:#f63;
       color:#fff;}
tbody td {vertical-align:top;
          padding-left:5px;
          padding-top:5px;}
tbody tr {background-color:#999;}
#title {text-align:center;}
```

Comment: Post your actual code in the question - not images of code,

Comment: done. this is the html for the homepage and the css for the site.